# Ring homomorphism is not one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix a linear map   $T: \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2   $ and let the subring of $End_{\mathbf{R} }(\mathbf{R}^2)$ generated by $T$ and $R$, i.e. $$\mathbf{R}[T] = \{c_0+c_1T + ... +c_nT^n : c_0, ... c_n \in \mathbf{R}\} $$

Define $\phi: \mathbf{R}[x] \to \mathbf{R} [T] $ by $$\phi(c_0 + c_1x + ... +c_nx^n)=c_0 + c_1T + ... + c_nT^n$$
for all $c_0+c_1x+... + c_nx^n \in \mathbf{R}[x]$ where $\mathbf{R}[x]$ is the polynomial ring in $x$. Then $\phi$ is clearly a ring homomorphism and surjective.

My question is how to show that $\phi$ is not injective

Some of my ideas: $T =T_A = A \vec x$. But ${T_A}^2 - tr(A)T_A+det(A)I$ does not always map to the zero polynomial, thus $T$ is not injective.

Answer (score 3):

The space $\mathbf{R}[T]$ is a subspace of $End_\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{R}^2)$ which is of dimension 4 over $\mathbf{R}$.
The space $\mathbf{R}[x]$ is infinite dimensional. You can't have an injective linear map from an infinite dimensional space to a finite dimensional one.